# Rotating a group individually in EAGLE

Tags: eaglecad

I've made a huge mistake when trying to create a 400-Pin LGA in EAGLE. I've right clicked when mindlessly placing pads and now they're all rotated by 90 degrees.

My OCD demmands that I set the rotation to 0 so they're easier to read but I cannot work out how to do this. You can see in this image what I'm talking about.
[image]

The manual lists how to set the angle of an object absolutely using the ROTATE command:

```
ROTATE =R0 NAME
```

But I cant figure out how to rotate a group of parts, without rotating them around a single part.

*Also some tips on how to mass rename these pads would help my sanity a lot...*

Comment: Eagle has a scripting language - ULP.  If you get really, really desperate `sed` will work on the files... but make a backup first (and don't have them open in eagle while modifying them externally).  If you do try to do it that way, I'd first move this part to its own library with nothing else in it, for simplicity.  At that point you could probably even use find and replace in a gui text editor.

Comment: I remember asking a question about Eagle and I think it was Chris that suggested me to start scripting for Eagle. I had no idea how to do it or where to start. Eventually, I started using python to generate some eagle actions, it was quite easy and very helpful (and fun and satisfying). There probably will not be a command or button for what you need, but there are many ways you can automate eagle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in the end, I fixed this by manually editing the part in a text editor. Removing all ROT=90 references for the pads removed any rotation transformations.

I modified the sequential-naming.ulp to work correctly with whilst in the library editor. I might take the time to extend this to work in other modes as the one included in my EAGLE installation only worked in schematics.